# I'm following the Django documentation 01 but it can't work for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-views

I'm a beginner at Django.

views.py/my_app

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
    
def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

urls.py/my_app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

urls.py/my_project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/', include('product.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/product

Using the URLconf defined in Zero.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The current path, product, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of `views.py` as well as `urls.py`.

Comment: have you tried this  http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/ with end / (backslash)

Comment: That doesn't work either